# Browser-sync tool for PHP file

Tags: php, html, web, browser-sync

The browser-sync works very well with HTML and CSS. However, it seems that it doesn't work with PHP files. When I click the .php files, the browser tries to download it rather than open it.
So, is there a similar tool for PHP development ? Or, are there some configurations I can do to adapt browser-sync to PHP files ?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You need a web stack (*usually apache/nginx/lightspeed/etc, PHP & MySQL*). Usually [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) are used on windows while you can install your own LAMP stack on linux/mac. (*When testing locally*)

Comment: LAMPP was installed and launched.